# Show 'sum' when multiple cells selected in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

If I select multiple cells in a Google Spreadsheet,
sum or count appears at the lowerright corner according to the data type.

Sum is shown for numbers, and count is shown for characters, dates or times.
But I'd like to see 'sum' for times. How can I change this setting?

I know I can do this using 'sum' function in a separate cell, but I would like to see this more conveniently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This now seems to work for me:

[image: WA41416 example]

Comment: Unfortunately, it only works if the sum is less than 24 hours. If the sum is more, it shows the sum modulo 24 hours which is not very practical.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible in Google Spreadsheets.

How are you planning on making the date summation? To return a date?

Comment: I'm using this spreadsheet to manage time. So I need to sum up times.

Comment: @user67275 Then you must use formulas to do so. The answer remains unchanged: what you're asking for isn't possible.